# C# usage in COM heavy application

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, automation

I would like to use C# for an application I'm building, but the application makes heavy use of automation (i.e. Excel, Word).

Is it feasible to use C# for such an application?  It used to be a nightmare to use C type languages for things like parameter lists with null arguments etc..

What are some tips to make things easier or should I just stick with VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what version of the language you're using. In .Net 4, C# supports named parameters (optional parameters). VB.Net has always had this. If you're not using .Net 4, I'd recommend using VB.Net for the interop bit - see [this post from Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsVarDim.aspx) for an example.

Comment: This is a compiler feature.  If you use the C# 4.0 compiler you can use optional parameters even in .Net 2.0 code.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for C# 4, which supports optional parameters and implicit `ref` arguments.
It will make your life much easier.

Whether you use C# 4 or C# 3, you should use the [Office Interop Extensions](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=46B6BF86-E35D-4870-B214-4D7B72B02BF9&displaylang=en#Instructions) from the [VSTO Power Tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2008/02/21/vsto-vsta-power-tools-v1-0.aspx); they will make your life even easier.

Comment: The typo makes this a bit unreadable. "Wait for C# for"?? I think you mean "C# foUr"